# Modify GroupBy for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        Team Division   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4
0     Flames  Pacific  4.0  1.0  3.0  1.0
1     Flames  Pacific  4.0  1.0  2.0  2.0
2     Oilers  Pacific  3.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
3    Canucks  Pacific  2.0  NaN  4.0  2.0
4   Senators  Eastern  1.0  4.0  4.0  3.0
5      Leats  Eastern  4.0  3.0  4.0  2.0
6      Leats  Eastern  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0
7    Canucks  Pacific  2.0  2.0  2.0  3.0
8     Oilers  Pacific  3.0  1.0  NaN  4.0
9     Flames  Pacific  3.0  4.0  4.0  3.0
10    Oilers  Pacific  2.0  3.0  1.0  4.0
11    Oilers  Pacific  4.0  NaN  2.0  1.0
12  Senators  Eastern  4.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
13     Leats  Eastern  2.0  4.0  4.0  NaN
```

I want to be able to group by the 'Team' and 'Division' column and then aggregate the data in the Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 columns. I currently have this code which is grouping by the 'Team' and then counting the number of 4's in each question column and dividing that value by the count in each column. I want to be able to group by the 'Division' column as well and possible other columns in the future.

How can this be done?

```
grouped = (df.filter(like='Q').groupby(df['Team'])
             .agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
          )
print(grouped)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to be able to maintain the non-Q columns.

Since you have a unique Division for each Team, just add the Division as grouper:

```
out = (df.filter(like='Q').groupby([df['Team'], df['Division']])
         .agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
      )
```

Output:

```
                         Q1        Q2        Q3   Q4
Team     Division                                   
Canucks  Pacific   0.000000  0.000000  0.500000  0.0
Flames   Pacific   0.666667  0.333333  0.333333  0.0
Leats    Eastern   0.500000  0.666667  1.000000  0.5
Oilers   Pacific   0.250000  0.000000  0.000000  0.5
Senators Eastern   0.500000  0.500000  0.500000  0.0
```

##### non unique Division per Team

With non-unique Division per Team, the logic is a bit more complex. Do you want to aggregate per Team AND keep the information on the multiple Divisions? OR do you just want to use Team/Division as grouper?

To aggregate only by Team but have one row per Division, you could craft a dictionary of aggregation functions to collect the potential multiple Divisions per Team and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the output:

```
funcs = ( {'Division': set}
        | {c: lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count() for c in df.filter(like='Q')}
        )
out = df.groupby('Team', as_index=False).agg(funcs).explode('Division')
```

This won't change anything with the provided example input, but would duplicates the rows if you had Teams with multiple Divisions.

For instance, if we replace "Pacific" in the first row by "Pacific2", this would give:

```
       Team  Division        Q1        Q2        Q3   Q4
0   Canucks   Pacific  0.000000  0.000000  0.500000  0.0
1    Flames   Pacific  0.666667  0.333333  0.333333  0.0
1    Flames  Pacific2  0.666667  0.333333  0.333333  0.0  # added a new row
2     Leats   Eastern  0.500000  0.666667  1.000000  0.5
3    Oilers   Pacific  0.250000  0.000000  0.000000  0.5
4  Senators   Eastern  0.500000  0.500000  0.500000  0.0
```

In contrast the first approach would aggregate the data independently for each combination of Team/Division.

```
                     Q1        Q2   Q3   Q4
Team     Division                          
Canucks  Pacific   0.00  0.000000  0.5  0.0
Flames   Pacific   0.50  0.500000  0.5  0.0
         Pacific2  1.00  0.000000  0.0  0.0
Leats    Eastern   0.50  0.666667  1.0  0.5
Oilers   Pacific   0.25  0.000000  0.0  0.5
Senators Eastern   0.50  0.500000  0.5  0.0
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Is there any way to do this for more than two columns? Can i groupby more than the Team and Division column but still aggregate my data by using the lambda function? Can i use your second approach but groupby four or five columns?

Comment: Yes you can, but it depends how you want to explode the data (all columns simultaneously or independently)

Comment: Could we maybe continue this conversation in chat so I can elaborate further?

Comment: Feel free to start a chat but I won't be able to respond interactively. I'll read it later.

Answer (score 0):

This may be correct:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your dataframe
data = {
    'Team': ['Flames', 'Flames', 'Oilers', 'Canucks', 'Senators', 'Leats', 'Leats', 'Canucks', 'Oilers', 'Flames', 'Oilers', 'Oilers', 'Senators', 'Leats'],
    'Division': ['Pacific', 'Pacific', 'Pacific', 'Pacific', 'Eastern', 'Eastern', 'Eastern', 'Pacific', 'Pacific', 'Pacific', 'Pacific', 'Pacific', 'Eastern', 'Eastern'],
    'Q1': [4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0, None, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0],
    'Q2': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, None, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0, None, 3.0, 4.0],
    'Q3': [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, None, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
    'Q4': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 3.0, None]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define aggregation functions
agg_funcs = {
    'Q1': lambda x: x.count() / x.size,
    'Q2': lambda x: x.count() / x.size,
    'Q3': lambda x: x.count() / x.size,
    'Q4': lambda x: x.count() / x.size
}

# Group by 'Team' and 'Division' and apply aggregation functions
result = df.groupby(['Team', 'Division']).agg(agg_funcs).reset_index()

# Rename the columns for clarity
result.columns = ['Team', 'Division', 'Q1_Aggregate', 'Q2_Aggregate', 'Q3_Aggregate', 'Q4_Aggregate']

print(result)
```

The output is:

```
Team Division  Q1_Aggregate  Q2_Aggregate  Q3_Aggregate  Q4_Aggregate
0   Canucks  Pacific      1.000000          0.50          1.00      1.000000
1    Flames  Pacific      1.000000          1.00          1.00      1.000000
2     Leats  Eastern      0.666667          1.00          1.00      0.666667
3    Oilers  Pacific      1.000000          0.75          0.75      1.000000
4  Senators  Eastern      1.000000          1.00          1.00      1.000000
```